# Where does the custom network icon show up?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I'm on a Windows 8.1 computer, and I've used the Group Policy editor (gpedit.msc) to customize the network icon for my home wireless network. The setting is under **Computer Configuration --> Windows Settings --> Security Settings --> Network List Manager Policies**. I can't seem to find any place where this icon is displayed in the operating system, however. Can anyone point me to where this icon should show up?

So far, I've looked:

1. In the Windows 8.1 network settings page <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> --> **Change PC Settings** --> **Network**
2. In the **Network and Sharing Center**
3. In the network connections sidebar <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> --> click network connection

[image]

Comment: Try setting the user permissions option to **User cannot change icon**: that should force the system to display the custom icon you chose.